# Some Advice on My Undergraduate Paper

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

My teacher wants me to read something about "Differential Geometry in $R^3$" and choose a topic as a paper.

Now I have finished these books. And I am interested in some topics below:

> $(1)$ Inequality about Integral of Curvature
>    $(2)$ Convex Surface
>    $(3)$ Isoperimetric Inequality
>    $(4)$ Constant Curvature Surface

All these things I have learned are in $R^3$. So one of my destination is to generalize these things into higher dimension. That is to say, I will consider the properties of hypersurface: $r:M\rightarrow{R^{n+1}}$ is an immersion and $M$ is an $n$ dimensional differential manifold.

So I want to ask some advice about these. Can someone provide some papers or books on these topics? Or give some useful ideas to me generously? If can, I will be very thankful.

Comment: Thorpe has an entire undergraduate [text](http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Geometry-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387903577)  about hypersurfaces.